# Athena joins and high cardinality partitions

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have an S3 table that catalogs requests. It contains a high number of "small" rows. Each row represents a request, and some small integers/flags that I like to filter my query by.

Each row also has a unique request_id.

Aside from this, I have another table with extended data for each request. This data is too big for a scan+filter approach. Example: It contains detailed information about request execution. If I were to trigger a full scan (or even a partial one) on this table, it would have to read too much data.

Can I adopt the original SQL approach of FOREIGN_KEYS, and partition my second table by request_id?

- Would that avoid a scan + filter on the extended table: Reading only the the request_ids that I filtered in the first table?
- Is there any problem with having a partion with such high cardinality on the second table?

  - Each S3 partition will only have one row
  - I will never scan this second table

`big_table` S3 partioining will look something like:
`s3://my_bucket/big_table/request_id=1234/data.json`

and the sql query will look something like:

```
SELECT FROM "small_table".request_id,"big_table".very_long_error_message
WHERE "small_table".date='2023-NOV-20', "small_table".error=true, 
      "small_table".request_id = "big_table".request_id
```

What will happen here? Will Athena only read the rows joined in "big_table"? Or will it scan and filter based on `request_id`? (How many big_table reads will I be paying for?)

Answer (score 0):

Athena is designed as an analytical query engine and is optimized to scan a lot of data efficiently. You should not worry too much about "it would have to read too much data."

If you are worried about the cost of the scans, it is recommended to use compression on your data, such as Parquet.

If you want to use partitions on your data for some reason, you can use a more scalable option for partitions, such as a hash function and taking the first two characters of the hashcode. It can give you the balance of having a bounded number of partitions,

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(MD5(request_id), 1, 2) AS hash_prefix
FROM
  your_table_name;
```

Comment: I don't understand: In athena, I pay by the amount that I read. It's true that athena athena/s3 will scaleup to whatever scale required to run my query: But I would be paying for this in $$$. I have alot of data in my tables, this can and does get very expensive. It seems to me that minimizing iops by pre-indexing the join is the best way to make sure athena does not read all of it.

Comment: How much data do you have? Athena costs $5.00 per TB of data scanned, which is even cheaper if you compress your data. 
There are a few partition options, such as partition by dates, which are very easy to implement, and you can also use the partition with the hash as suggested above. 
Creating "an index" is impossible as there is a limit to the number of partitions you can have in Athena, as it is going against the design pattern of big data queries. The main power of Athena is in its distributed computing capabilities, unlike traditional RDBMS.

Comment: My "small row table" has very small row with "sane" ammounts of data. It produces < 100MB per day, and is partitioned by date. I scan and filter on that table.

My big table has ~1TB per day, I don't want to scan + filter on that one. I want to scan and filter on the little table, and then join on the few remaining entries in the big table. That way I scan on 100s of MB, and join on a few rows in the big table (a few MBs more). The results I want only include a filtered few rows from the big table, I don't want to scan all of it.